# Can't turn on image stabilisation on iPhone 6/6+ with iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus, image-stabilization

Ok so I ran down into a wall and really not sure what to do.
I'm writing a camera app. Finished it actually. Writing on Swift mostly.
In the app I have an option to turn image stabilization on and off, which should be pretty straightforward. Code goes like this (stillImageOutput is  AVCaptureStillImageOutput) :

```
 func setStabilisation(state:Bool){
   if self.stillImageOutput!.stillImageStabilizationSupported{
       if state{
           self.stillImageOutput!.automaticallyEnablesStillImageStabilizationWhenAvailable = true
       }
       else{
           self.stillImageOutput!.automaticallyEnablesStillImageStabilizationWhenAvailable = false
       }
   }
   else {presentMessegePopUp("Image stabilisation is not supported")}
}
```

presentMessegePopUp is simply a wrap for Alert.
One of the problems is that I have only iPhone5S and cant really debug it. But! testing on 4 devices 6/6+ via beta FlightTest, all of them get this popup. Meaning they are getting false on 'stillImageStabilizationSupported'. This is when on my phone it works just fine ...

According to this article by Apple all phones up to 6+ are supposed to support it:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2409/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40015038-CH1-SINGLE_SHOT__VIDEO__HDR (Optical Image Stabilization section)

I tried to find if something can interfere with this property but so far (week+) I found nothing.

Can any one help please?

Comment: Why are you using `!` on your first access to `stillImageOutput` and then `?` on the next two? I feel like if you knew it wasn't `nil` on the first line, you could be reasonably sure it's still not `nil` on the next two...

Comment: You are correct. Overlooked it somehow